# How can I print the same variable into a string several times?

Tags: c, printf

I have a format string like this:

```
buf[] = "A%d,B%d,C%d,D%d,F%d,G%d,H%d,I%d,J%d";
```

and I want to insert the same integer for each `%d` so I use:

```
 int val = 6;
 sprintf(buf2, buf, val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val);
```

Can I use `sprintf` in a way that only requires me to write `val` once, and `sprintf` will use it for each `%d`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can use `%1$d` everytime. The `1$` references the second argument, you could obviously do it with other arguments, too.

Demo: http://codepad.org/xVmdJkpN

Note that the position specifier is a POSIX extension - so it might not work with every single compiler. If you need it to work e.g. with the Visual C++ compiler, consider using the ugly way of repeating the argument or do not use a printf-style function at all. Another option would be using a POSIX-compatible sprintf implementation or using multiple calls to append one number everytime in a loop (in case the format string is built dynamically which would prevent you from specifying the correct number of arguments).

---

On a side-note, `sprintf` should be avoided. Use `snprintf(buf2, sizeof(buf2), ....)` instead. Of course this requires `buf2` to have a static size known at compile-time - but if you allocate it manually you can simply use the variable containing the length instead of `sizeof(buf2)`.

Comment: You were right the first time:  use `%1$d` because `val` is the first argument to the format string.

Comment: What are the benefits of using snprintf over sprintf?

Comment: Indeed. That happens when you use variable names like that. `fmt` would be much more appropriate for `buf`. @OliCharlesworth: Is anything of `printf` even standardized? @Flyphe: You protect your code against buffer overflows.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It's apparently a POSIX extension: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Custom_format_placeholders

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: which C standard? My gcc 4.2.1 doesn't like it with -std=c99 but strangely my gcc 4.3.2 accepts it even with -std=c89

Comment: @WilliamMorris: It's not in any C standard, AFAIK.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me in Windows using MinGw.

Answer (score 6):

There is no standard (i.e. portable) way of doing this.

Comment: The OP did explicitly not ask for a standardized way though. I don't think there is a really good reason to not use any useful extension nowadays just because they aren't in the standard. Especially if you don't write some super-awesome library everyone is going to use soon!

Comment: @ThiefMaster: But he also didn't specify a particular platform.  The POSIX extension doesn't work in Visual C++, for example.