# Is there a way to have printf reference only one instance of a variable for the same conversion character repeated x amount of times?

Tags: c, printf

I was thinking there might be a "trick" to compound the right side of `printf()`?

or example this like...

```
float x;
printf("%.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f \n", x, x, x, x );
```

to something like this

```
float x;
printf("%.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f \n", magicArrayOfxAmountofx);
```

(i know this is wrong - and I mainly asking for cosmetic and magical purposes and I was thinking there must be a "trick" to compound the right side of `printf()` into one variable if it is the same value? an array maybe? As my variable name is much longer than `x` and I would like to keep it named the same way and not let this `printf()` line be too long!)

Comment: A different approach but this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572271/how-can-i-print-the-same-variable-into-a-string-several-times?rq=1

Comment: That *magic array* is called iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is. On POSIX systems, `printf()` lets you specify which argument it should print using the `n$` modifier in the conversion specifiers, where `n` means the number of the argument to be printed, starting from one. You can exploit this fact:

```
printf("%1$f %1$f %1$f %1$f\n", 1.0f);
```

Comment: WHat does the compiler says to that when the -Wformat warning is on? I'm wondering

Comment: @Gui13 Nothing. This is a POSIX extension to the C standard library. (And is there anyone who cares about non-POSIX systems? I don't, for one.)

Comment: For what it's worth, prior to POSIX 2008, this was not part of the base POSIX standard; it was optional functionality (in the XSI option group).

Comment: @R. which could mean that it doesn't work on BSD and derived systems, such as OS X, no? AFAIK on many aspects these follow only really oldish versions of the POSIX standard.

Comment: I am getting an error with this line... `    printf("The value of 2( %$1f )**3 + 3( %$1f) **2 + 4(%$1f) + 5 = 65", f_var );
`  Do I need to escape this some how?

Comment: @JensGustedt I don't know which version of POSIX it appears in, nor in which year was it incorporated, but this works for sure on OS X.

Comment: @user1787331 You used the wrong conversion specifier. It's `%1$f` and not `%$1f`.

Comment: the error in xcode is "Invalid conversion specifier '$"

Comment: lol. Thanks for figuring that out before I posted the error.

Comment: @user1787331 Read my comment, really.

Comment: @Jens: Thankfully, I'm pretty sure those also follow XSI, at least mostly. POSIX base, without XSI, seems really intended to be the "portable operating system interface" that's how *all modern operating systems* should be working, whereas XSI seems to be "this is the extra stuff you need to support legacy unix apps". Moving this `printf` feature to base seems to have little *practical* effect for compatibility, but indicates a sentiment that it should be supported on modern/new operating systems even if they don't aim to be unixish.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but in this particular example it looks like you'd be better served with a loop, to cut down on code duplication in the format string as well as the variable list. Something like:

```
for(k=0; k<4; ++k)
    printf("%.1f ", x);
printf("\n")
```

(And of course if you're going to do this often, you'd want to put that code in a function anyway.)